# how to solve import cannot be resolved error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I am getting that error :

```
The import android.graphics.TableMaskFilter cannot be resolved
```

But I have seen TableMaskFilter class in android.graphics package of android-sdk folder and I am unable to see it inside the android4.0.3 library in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. `TableMaskFilter` is annotated with `@hide`, which means it's definition is stripped from `android.jar`.